# Add textField data to a list. Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jlist

I want to create a little swing application that takes input from the text field and puts it in a `ArrayList`. The code is not working and I need some help.

EDIT. Fixed the syntax. Now the i cant get the code to work. It wont add the textfield data to the list. Please help.

Here is the code:

```
public class GUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

JButton button = new JButton(" >> CLICK ME <<");
final JTextField txt = new JTextField("Enter player name.");
static List <String> player = new ArrayList <String> ();

public GUI(){

    txt.setBounds(1, 1, 300, 30);

    JButton button = new JButton(" >> ADD PLAYER <<");

    button.setBounds(40, 40, 200, 40);

    setLayout(null);
    add(txt);
    add(button);

    button.addActionListener(this);


}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource().equals(button)) {
        player.add(txt.getText());
        System.out.println("Added: " + txt.getText() + " to the list.");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Adding the textField data to the list did not work.");


}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("Memory Game. Add player function.");
    frame1.getContentPane().add(new GUI());

    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame1.setSize(310, 130);
    frame1.setVisible(true);

}
```

I am new to swing and have only been coding for a couple of weeks. :/

Comment: 1) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Comment: @AbdiTem Whats your new Question?

Comment: @LukasHieronimusAdler the adding function is not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can get text from `JtextField` `getText()` method and use `add()` to add it to a `list player`. Given below is the code.

```
player.add(txt.getText());
```

Check the links below for more details:

- [How to Use Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html)
- [getText()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText--)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the ActionListener to the JButton with

```
button.addActionListener(this);
```

And then add in the actionPerformed the text of the JTextfield to the list :

```
player.add(txt.getText());
```

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my question, please feel free to read through it. :)

Comment: Try to know (with system.out.println or debug mode) what is the source in e.getSource(), if it is really your button.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to get the text from the textfield.

```
player.add(txt.getText())
```

This will do what you want to have.

There you will get the current String which is in the TextField. So you can add it into your List.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my question, please feel free to read through it. :)